# Submitting form in wordpress plugin

Tags: html, forms, plugins

I am new to wordpress and currently making a plugin.

I am getting list of authors using

```
<?php wp_dropdown_users(array('name' => 'author'));?>
```

Now when submitting my form I want to retain the current value entered by the user but as soon I submit the form the values get back to the default ones.

I have searched on net and tryed alot but somehow not able to do this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing [`wp_dropdown_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_users) there is apparently a `'selected'` parameter. So in theory, you could probably pass the posted value in here.

```
// set to the posted value, but you might be able to do this differently, depending on how you are storing the data
$selected = isset($_POST['author']) ? $_POST['author'] : false;

$args = array( 'name' => 'author',
               'selected' => $selected );

wp_dropdown_user( $args );
```

Comment: It was helpful..

Comment: If it was the answer, then please accept it as the answer so we can close this question.